# Using UI5 with a ASP.Net oData back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, sapui5

I want to create a back-end by `ASP.NET Web Application API` for a `SAPUI5` front-end.

The front-end side is so simple and works with mock-server fine, and has no problem with internal mock-server.

However I want to use the app with a real `ASP.NET` back-end server.

I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint) for creating the `ASP.NET` back-end server.

The only part that is a little bit different from the original tutorial is the `WebAppConfig.cs` file which I revealed it here:

```cs
using CimplySkills_Backend.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Data.Edm;
using Microsoft.Data.Edm.Csdl;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Batch;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace CimplySkills_Backend
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // allow CORS
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web-API-Routen
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // define HTTP access
            /*
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            */
            // enable batch
            var odataBatchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);

            // enable queries
            config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

            // set entities
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<CountriesSet>("CountriesSet");
            builder.Entity<LocationsSet>().HasOptional(x => x.Country).CascadeOnDelete(false);


            //Define version
            Version odataVersion2 = new Version(2, 0);
            builder.DataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
            builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;

            IEdmModel edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
            edmModel.SetEdmVersion(odataVersion2);
            edmModel.SetEdmxVersion(odataVersion2);

            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "sap/opu/odata/cimtag/ODATA_SKILLS_SRV/",
                // routePrefix: null,
                model: edmModel,
                batchHandler: odataBatchHandler);

            // resolve "No non-OData HTTP route registered"
            // config.EnableDependencyInjection();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when the `UI5` app try to send a batch request to the back-end, it can send the request and access the end-point correctly, the response is also successfully received, however there is a problem in the response that it will repeat the request again and again, and the binding is not triggered. Look at the following picture:

[image: Batch request from UI5 to ASP.NET]

First of all, it seems I am not the only person who had this problem, for example [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12935159/sapui5-with-aspnet-odata-api-v2.html) somebody else also had the same problem.

I analyzed the response from this `ASP.NET` server with a same batch response to an `SAP ABAP` server (which is the standard back-end for `SAPUI5` applications) and there are a few differences.

For example here a batch response in `SAP`:

```
--BD335BC5DB87B4F290C21DB6C0A9D3650
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 538
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 347
dataserviceversion: 2.0
sap-metadata-last-modified: Tue, 07 Apr 2020 13:02:03 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache

{
"d":{
    "__metadata":{
            "id":"https://xyz.de:5698/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMJZ_ODATA_COMMON_SRV/AuthSet'ZMJZ_SECTY')",                            "uri":"https://xyz.de:5698/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMJZ_ODATA_COMMON_SRV/AuthSet'ZMJZ_SECTY')",                           "type":"ZMJZ_ODATA_COMMON_SRV.Auth"
        },
    "Object":"ZMJZ_SECTY",
    "FlagCreate":true,
    "FlagRead":true,
    "FlagUpdate":true,
    "FlagDelete":true
    }
}
--BD335BC5DB87B4F290C21DB6C0A9D3650--
```

And here a batch response from `ASP.NET`:

```
--batchresponse_988aa133-3a4a-413c-9109-f5f7786e7e78
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *

{
  "d":{
    "results":[
      {
        "__metadata":{

        },"ID":1,"name":"Germany"
      },{
        "__metadata":{

        },"ID":2,"name":"France"
      },{
        "__metadata":{

        },"ID":3,"name":"Iran"
      },{
        "__metadata":{

        },"ID":4,"name":"USA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
--batchresponse_988aa133-3a4a-413c-9109-f5f7786e7e78--
```

If we look carefully, we will see there is a `Content-Length` property that is appear two times in the `SAP` response while it does not exist in the `ASP.NET` response at all. (It is only my guess that it is the source of the problem)

1. The first question of mien is how can I modify the batch response in `ASP.NET` to add the `Content-Length` in the response content also. *(Please notice that the `Content-Length` exist inside the response header and what you see here is the response payload or the response content itself!)*
2. The second question is more general, do you have any other suggestion for fixing this issue?